# R - operation between groups and NOT within groups

Tags: r

I have a question that is similar to this one : [Operations between groups with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736289/operations-between-groups-with-dplyr)

I want to compute the number of days between the Last trading day of my first group, and the second group, the between the second and the third.

I group the data by expiry month.

```
Date      `Last trading day`  `Expiry month`    
<date>     <dttm>              <date>                    
1 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                
2 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                 
3 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                 
4 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                 
5 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                
6 2011-07-15 2011-12-15 00:00:00 2012-01-10                 
7 2011-07-15 2011-12-15 00:00:00 2012-01-10                
8 2011-07-15 2011-04-15 00:00:00 2012-05-10
```

What I'm trying to obtain :

```
Date      `Last trading day`  `Expiry month`         `Time_dif`   
<date>     <dttm>              <date>                    <dbl> 
1 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                 59  
2 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                 59 
3 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                 59 
4 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                 59
5 2011-07-15 2011-10-17 00:00:00 2011-11-10                 59 
6 2011-07-15 2011-12-15 00:00:00 2012-01-10                 122  
7 2011-07-15 2011-12-15 00:00:00 2012-01-10                 122
8 2011-07-15 2012-04-15 00:00:00 2012-05-10                (here it will be the number of days between this group and the next)
```

Can someone help please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code joins the original dataset with a summarised version which gets the next (last) trading date using `lead`. I've changed the names of your variables to make it easier to code.

```
names(df) <- c("Date","last_trading_date", "Expiry_month")

library(dplyr)
inner_join(df, group_by(df, Expiry_month) %>%
   summarise(last_trading_date = max(last_trading_date)) %>%
   mutate(next_date = lead(last_trading_date), Time_dif = next_date-last_trading_date)) %>%
  select(-next_date)
```

---

```
        Date last_trading_date Expiry_month Time_dif
1 2011-07-15        2011-10-17   2011-11-10  59 days
2 2011-07-15        2011-10-17   2011-11-10  59 days
3 2011-07-15        2011-10-17   2011-11-10  59 days
4 2011-07-15        2011-10-17   2011-11-10  59 days
5 2011-07-15        2011-10-17   2011-11-10  59 days
6 2011-07-15        2011-12-15   2012-01-10 122 days
7 2011-07-15        2011-12-15   2012-01-10 122 days
8 2011-07-15        2012-04-15   2012-05-10  NA days
```

Comment: Works perfectly well. Thanks a lot! :)